# "It is!" I squealed at the same time she cried, "It's not!" - Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence, speech, sentence-patterns

Is this sentence apt? -

> "*It is!*" I squealed at the same time she cried, "*It's not!*"

Comment: There's a difference between "apt" and "correct", which are you after? Also this is currently proofreading which is off-topic unless you identify a source of concern in the text.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be right?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. Perhaps you're concerned that it's a run-on sentence, but it's saved by an implied "that": "'It is!' I squealed at the same time [that] she cried, 'It's not!'". Meaning that the core of the sentence is "I squealed," and "at the same time she cried" is a dependent clause. You could also recast the sentence as two independent clauses: "'It is!'" I squealed; at the same time she cried, 'It's not!'". You might also be concerned about punctuation in sentences containing direct quotes. The exclamation mark in "It is!" stands in for a comma.